# ¿Qué es yield en python?

Tags: python, yield

¿Cuál es el uso de la palabra clave `yield` en Python? ¿Qué hace?

Estoy intentando entender el siguiente código<sup>**1**</sup>:

```py
def _get_child_candidates(self, distance, min_dist, max_dist):
    if self._leftchild and distance - max_dist < self._median:
        yield self._leftchild
    if self._rightchild and distance + max_dist >= self._median:
        yield self._rightchild
```

La llamada de la función (o método en este caso) es:

```py
result, candidates = [], [self]
while candidates:
    node = candidates.pop()
    distance = node._get_dist(obj)
    if distance <= max_dist and distance >= min_dist:
        result.extend(node._values)
    candidates.extend(node._get_child_candidates(distance, min_dist, max_dist))
return result
```

¿Qué sucede cuando se llama al método _get_child_candidates? ¿Devuelve una lista o un solo elemento? ¿Es llamado de nuevo? ¿Cuándo se detendrán las llamadas subsiguientes?

---

<sub>1. El código proviene de Jochen Schulz (jrschulz), quien creó una excelente biblioteca de Python para espacios métricos. Este es el enlace a la fuente completa: [Module mspace](http://well-adjusted.de/~jrschulz/mspace/).</sub>

Comment: yield y metaclases son 2 cosas muy distintas.

Comment: @abulafia ¿por qué voy a borrar el comentario?

Comment: @eyllanesc Para no inducir a confusión a futuros lectores, ya que la pregunta no menciona (ahora) las metaclases por ningún sitio, ni el código las usa, y entonces no se entiende el por qué de ese comentario.

Comment: @abulafia pues eso es parte del historial, no trae confusión ya que señala algo claro: esos conceptos son diferentes.

Comment: @Adolfo He editado las etiquetas para quitar poo y clases, pues realmente `yield` no está relacionado. Puede usarse en una función normal y el hecho de que en este caso sea un método de una clase es anecdótico y no influye en la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias @abulafia y eyllanesc por las correcciones. Y en especial abulafia por la respuesta tan bien esplicada. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: No estoy muy familiarizado con todas las reglas del stackoverflow, no se si en los comentarios esta permitido agradecer. De estar prohibido borrare este y el comentario anterior

Comment: @AdolfoCorrea los comentarios son *ciudadanos de segunda clase* que tienen permisos más abiertos que las preguntas/respuestas por lo que los agradecimientos son adecuados aqui. Por otro la mejor forma de agradecer una respuesta correcta es marcarla, si no sabes como hacerlo entonces revisa denuevo el [tour] :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Explicación sencilla (y falsa)

Un `yield` puede entenderse como una especie de `return` que no retorna realmente del todo.

Cuando ejecutando una función se encuentra `yield loquesea`, la función retorna el valor `loquesea`, pero "guarda por donde iba". Posteriormente se puede reanudar en el punto donde se dejó, y seguirá ejecutándose por la instrucción siguiente al `yield`.

Es frecuente por tanto encontrar `yield` dentro de un bucle, de modo que cada vez que la función se "reanuda" se itera un nuevo valor del bucle y se "retorna" ese nuevo valor.

Cuando la función llega a su final, se produce un "verdadero" `return` (que retorna `None`) y entonces ya no se puede reanudar más.

## Explicación verdadera (y no tan complicada)

Cuando python está compilando el programa (sí, Python compila todo el código a una representación binaria intermedia antes de pasar a ejecutarlo) si encuentra una función (llamémosla por ejemplo `foo`) que contiene una o más instrucciones `yield`, la marca de forma especial. Esa función será un *generador*.

Cuando el código llame a la función `foo()` ésta no se ejecuta de forma normal. De hecho ni siquiera comienza su ejecución. El intérprete hace que el resultado de `foo()` sea un *iterador*. Es decir, por ejemplo, en:

```
v = foo()
```

`v` pasaría a contener un *iterador*. Un iterador es un objeto al que se le puede hacer `next()`.

Cuando se haga `next(v)` *entonces sí*, el código de `foo()` comenzará a ejecutarse, y se pausará cuando alcance la instrucción `yield`. Por ejemplo:

```
r = next(v)
```

haría que comenzara el código de `foo`, y que ante el primer `yield` el flujo retornara, y el valor retornado por `next()` sería precisamente el que `yield` especificó.

Más adelante puede hacerse de nuevo `next(v)` y entonces la función `foo` reanudará su ejecución donde estaba (después del `yield`) y seguirá hasta encontrar otro `yield`, y así sucesivamente.

Cuando al hacer `next(v)` la ejecución de la función alcanza su final "real" y por tanto retorna `None`, el itérprete lanzará la excepción `StopIteration`.

Por tanto si queremos iterar por todos los valores que vaya "retornando" esa función hasta que se acaben haríamos:

```
v = foo()
while True:
    try:
        r = next(v)
        print("Valor retornado:", r)
    except StopIteration:
        print("Y no hay más valores")
```

Pero Python tiene una sintaxis mucho más elegante para hacer esto mismo, a la que estamos bien acostumbrados aún si no sabíamos cómo lo hacía "por debajo". Se trata del bucle `for`. Lo anterior equivale a:

```
for r in foo():
   print("Valor retornado:", r)
print("Y no hay más valores")
```

`for` se ocupa "por debajo" de recoger el iterador retornado por `foo()` e ir haciendo `next()` sobre él, asignando cada valor a `r` hasta que se detecta `StopIteration` y se sale del bucle.

El `for` de las *list comprehensions* también funciona con generadores, de modo que puedes hacer algo como:

```
lista = [r for r in foo()]
```

y así se creará una lista con todos los valores devueltos por el generador. También podríamos abreviarlo a:

```
lista = list(foo())
```

ya que `list` espera un iterable como parámetro, por lo que internamente iterará sobre él, y lo mismo le da que sea un generador que una verdadera lista u otro tipo de objeto, con tal de que implemente el interfaz iterable, es decir, que admita que se le pueda hacer `next()`.

Los generadores son preferibles a las listas cuando el número de elementos es grande, pues se van creando a medida que se necesitan, en vez de tener todos los elementos creados de antemano. Un generador podria incluso no terminar nunca. Por ejemplo, se podría pensar en un generador que cada vez que haces `next()` te devuelva el siguiente primo.

## Para qué se usan

Como he dicho el uso habitual es para hacer generadores que después se puedan iterar en un bucle for.

Pero durante un tiempo (antes de que Python recibiera los keywords `async`/`await`, cosa que sucedió en la versión 3.5), se usaban también como una forma un poco enrevesada de conseguir programación asíncrona mediante tareas cooperativas.

Ya que `yield` no retorna del todo sino que puede seguir por donde se dejó, puede utilizarse para implementar el concepto de *corutina* que permite a varias funciones entremezclar sus ejecuciones produciendo la ilusión de que ambas avanzan más o menos a la vez, sin necesidad de usar programación multihilo, posibilitando la programación asíncrona.

Pero esa es otra historia. En tu código se está usando (aunque no lo parezca) como un generador.

Esto se debe a que la llamada a la función aparece como parámetro de `extend`. Es decir, el código hace el equivalente de:

```
lista.extend(foo())
```

Ya que `extend` espera como parámetro un iterable, lo que hará será iterar por los valores devueltos por el generador `foo`, para añadirlos a `lista`. Es decir, es equivalente a haber hecho:

```
lista.extend([v for v in foo()])
```

o

```
lista.extend(list(foo())
```

## Respondiendo ya a tus preguntas:

> 1. ¿Qué sucede cuando se llama al método `_get_child_candidates`?

Se crea un iterable, y eso es lo que retorna.

> 2. ¿Devuelve una lista o un solo elemento?

Ni lo uno ni lo otro, retorna un iterable. Pero según el contexto en que lo uses, probablemente se iterará sobre ese iterable. En tu caso, como ya expliqué, estás pasando el iterable como parámetro de `extend()` por lo que éste llamará a `next()` sobre el iterable hasta que lo agote. Cada vez que lo llama se ejecuta hasta el siguiente `yield`.

Si observamos el código de `_get_child_candidates`, vemos no contiene bucles y sólo hay dos `yield` por lo que iterar sobre este caso producirá sólo dos iteraciones como máximo (si ambos `if` fuesen ciertos, si no puede incluso iterar cero veces)

> 3. ¿Es llamado de nuevo? ¿Cuándo se detendrán las llamadas subsiguientes?

A riesgo de ser pesado y aunque ya debe de estar claro, la función sólo se llama una vez. Pero se reanuda varias veces, hasta que ya no ejecute más `yield` y llegue a su final. En este caso puede generar 0, 1 ó 2 resultados según se cumplan o no los `if`

De modo que la lista sobre la que se ha hecho `.extend()` se extenderá con el hijo izquierdo, o el derecho, o ambos, o ninguno :-)

## Sin yield

Para cerrar, decir que la función `_geg_child_candidates()` perfectamente se podría haber implementado sin usar `yield`. Se podría crear una lista que contenga al hijo izquierdo, o el derecho, o ambos, o ninguno, según corresponda, y retornar esa lista. Así:

```
def _get_child_candidates(self, distance, min_dist, max_dist):
    result = []
    if self._leftchild and distance - max_dist < self._median:
        result.append(self._leftchild)
    if self._rightchild and distance + max_dist >= self._median:
        result.append(self._rightchild)
    return result
```

Desde fuera, en este caso, se usaría exactamente de la misma forma:

```
candidates.extend(node._get_child_candidates(distance, min_dist, max_dist))
```

`.extend()` espera algo sobre lo que iterar, y en este caso estaría recibiendo una lista, lo que le vale. Añadiría a `candidates` los elementos de la lista retornada por `node._get_child_candidates()`. En el caso original, recibía un iterable, lo que también le valía.

No veo mucha ventaja en este caso en usar un generador, pues la lista a crear es realmente muy pequeña. En casos en que la lista pueda ser enorme, el generador tiene la ventaja ya comentada de que es más ligero en el uso de memoria, y si cada elemento tarda un tiempo en ser calculado, el generador te permite obtener el siguiente elemento tan pronto esté listo, sin tener que esperar a generar una lista entera de ellos. Este método es lo que se llama "*lazy*" (perezoso), porque un dato no se computa hasta que no se necesita.