# porque es posible asignar un iterable infinito a una variable?

Tags: python, iteradores

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar itertools, viendo un ejemplo de el uso de la funcion cycle(iterable) encontre la siguiente imagen

[image: Ejemplo uso de cycle]

Me causo mucha curiosidad, ya que la funcion cycle genera un iterable infinito agregando todos los elementos de la lista dada en este caso y cuando los agrega todos, agrega de nuevo los items de la lista desde el inicio, asi sucesivamente, asi que me pregunto como es posible que un iterable infinito pueda asignarse a una variable?, si es infinito no seria imposible guardarlo en memoria ya que esta es finita?, la respuesta se encuentra en la forma en que trabaja la funcion, pero no tengo idea.

Comment: El *iterable infinito* no se guarda en la variable se guarda un objeto de tipo iterador, si tu dices que se guarda un iterador infinito entonces su programa no pasaría de la definición de la variable y de quedaría *estancado* ahí

Comment: Un iterable sólo necesita producir y entregar un valor a la vez. No necesita producir **toda** la lista antes de entregar el primer valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para entender los iteradores y el módulo itertools, antes debes comprender [yield](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/254318/80870).

Documentación de Python, [equivalencia en código del método cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle). Es un ciclo infinito con yield.

```
def cycle(iterable):
    # cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D A B C D ...
    saved = []
    for element in iterable:
        yield element
        saved.append(element)
    while saved:
        for element in saved:
              yield element
```

Los iteradores son objetos, y como tal son asignables a variables. La variable toma la referencia del objeto, no su ejecución. El iterador va devolviendo valores, uno a uno, a medida que se le van solicitando. Posiblemente la confusión está en creer que un iterador se ejecuta igual que una función.
Un ejemplo:

```
def generator():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        yield i
```

El código anterior tiene un ciclo infinito (también puede ser una serie de valores finitos), y el mismo es perfectamente asignable a una variable:

```
y = generador()
# imprimimos algunos valores
print(next(y)) # 1
print(next(y)) # 2
print(next(y)) # 3
```

Se puede extraer cualquier cantidad de valores de este generador, ya que es infinito, sin embargo en caso de iterar sobre el generador, hay que poner una condición de salida para que no entre en bucle infinito, a menos que el generador sea finito.

```
for n in y:
    if n > 10:
        break
    print(n)
# Imprime 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 (un valor por linea)
```